# Does probabilistic graphical models include kalman filters?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, kalman-filter

Do filters (specifically Kalman filters) come under probabilistic graphical models? If not where do they fit in?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indeed they do and it is quite straightforward to think about them in terms of graphical models (at least for some of us) if you don't like to remember specific formula for every model. You create nodes for velocity and position (represented as Gaussians with mean and std) and attach them to your observed node  and repeat that for all the timesteps (with the difference that first node for position and vleocity is independent of the history and the future one will depend, which makes sense since we assume tracking object is not performing any jumps). You can find (simplified) representation of Kalman filters as graphical models in Chritopher Bishop's 3rd lecture from MLSS 2013: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJSEQeH40hM.